# How do I use JQuery to replace all occurring of a certain word in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I've made two different attempts to replace all occurrences of a single word from a webpage using JQuery in a Chrome extension. Both attempts *kind of* worked, but neither worked as a *universal* method for replacing all occurrences of a word from a webpage.

How can I write a script that replaces all occurrences of a certain word in a webpage?

Read on for details of the 2 different attempts which both *kind of* worked but failed for different reasons.

Attempt 1: Replace the text of nodes that have no children. This fails in cases where child nodes are used for formatting. For example, it fails when parsing the following:

```
<p>StringToReplace <strong>doesn't</strong> get replaced!</p>
```

The exact code I used for this attempt is:

```
$("*").each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 
        $(this).text(replaceStrings($(this).text()));
    } 
}
```

(replaceStrings is a separate function with a bunch of arbitrary calls to replace)

Attempt 2: Replace the HTML of nodes that probably only contain text (e.g. `p`). This fails because some of the webpages my script needs to work on have text appearing right inside tags like body. If I try replacing the HTML of body, it has an undesired side-effect of breaking functionality on some pages. IMO it would be a nightmare to try to handle every edge case where site functionality is impaired by replacing HTML of `body` or `div`s high up the DOM tree.

The code I used for this second attempt:

```
$("*").each(function () { 
    if (
        $(this)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "font"
        || $(this)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span"
        || $(this)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "p"
        //|| $(this)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "body"
        // || $(this)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "div" 
        ){
        $(this).html(replaceStrings($(this).html()));
    }
}
```

How can I write a script that replaces all occurrences of a certain word in a webpage?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, the selector for your second attempt could easily be written as `$('font, span, p')` negating the need to check `nodeName`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the plugin in the first answer because it only works 1 level deep. Here's a version that goes through the entire structure under the selected element.

Usage: `$(".content").replaceText("visitor","John Doe");`

```
// Replace occurences of 'search' with 'replace' anywhere in the element. 
// New HTML tags will be rendered, except if 'text_only' is true. 
$.fn.replaceText = function(search, replace, text_only) {  
    return this.each(function(){  
        var v1, v2, rem = [];
        $(this).find("*").andSelf().contents().each(function(){
            if(this.nodeType === 3) {
                v1 = this.nodeValue;
                v2 = v1.replace(search, replace);
                if(v1!=v2) {
                    if(!text_only && /<.*>/.test(v2)) {  
                        $(this).before( v2 );  
                        rem.push(this);  
                    }
                    else this.nodeValue = v2;  
                }
            }
        });
        if(rem.length) $(rem).remove();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thoroughly tested this, but it should point you in the right direction:

```
$('*', 'body')
    .andSelf()
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    })
    .each(function() {
        this.nodeValue = replaceStrings(this.nodeValue);
    });
```

(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery/926881#926881) along with help from [this plugin](http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-3.js))

Comment: Thanks roryf but I've already implemented hubbl's solution and it's working perfectly so I probably won't test this one out.