# Javascript Regex to replace text NOT in html attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like a Javascript Regex to wrap a given list of of words in a given start (`<span>`) and end tag (i.e. `</span>`), but only if the word is actually "visible text" on the page, and not inside of an html attribute (such as a link's title tag, or inside of a `<script></script>` block.

I've created a JS Fiddle with the basics setup:  http://jsfiddle.net/4YCR6/1/

Comment: As the others said, its usually not the best idea to handle HTML with a regex. But there are cases where its just the easiest way. Try this: [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YCR6/4/) On [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/NMazXVpKfE)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241169/highlight-search-terms-select-only-leaf-nodes

Answer (score 41):

HTML is too complex to reliably parse with a regular expression.

If you're looking to do this client-side, you can create a document fragment and/or disconnected DOM node (neither of which is displayed anywhere) and initialize it with your HTML string, then walk through the resulting DOM tree and process the text nodes. (Or use a library to help you do that, although it's actually quite simple.)

Here's a DOM walking example. This example is *slightly* simpler than your problem because it just updates the text, it doesn't add new elements to the structure (wrapping parts of the text in `span`s involves updating the structure), but it should get you going. Notes on what you'll need to change at the end.

```
var html =
    "<p>This is a test.</p>" +
    "<form><input type='text' value='test value'></form>" +
    "<p class='testing test'>Testing here too</p>";
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var body = document.createElement('body');
var node, next;

// Turn the HTML string into a DOM tree
body.innerHTML = html;

// Walk the dom looking for the given text in text nodes
walk(body);

// Insert the result into the current document via a fragment
node = body.firstChild;
while (node) {
  next = node.nextSibling;
  frag.appendChild(node);
  node = next;
}
document.body.appendChild(frag);

// Our walker function
function walk(node) {
  var child, next;

  switch (node.nodeType) {
    case 1:  // Element
    case 9:  // Document
    case 11: // Document fragment
      child = node.firstChild;
      while (child) {
        next = child.nextSibling;
        walk(child);
        child = next;
      }
      break;
    case 3: // Text node
      handleText(node);
      break;
  }
}

function handleText(textNode) {
  textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(/test/gi, "TEST");
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/unuli5)

The changes you'll need to make will be in `handleText`. Specifically, rather than updating `nodeValue`, you'll need to:

- Find the index of the beginning of each word within the `nodeValue` string.
- Use [`Node#splitText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-38853C1D) to split the text node into up to three text nodes (the part before your matching text, the part that *is* your matching text, and the part following your matching text).
- Use `document.createElement` to create the new `span` (this is literally just `span = document.createElement('span')`).
- Use [`Node#insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) to insert the new `span` in front of the third text node (the one containing the text following your matched text); it's okay if you didn't need to create a third node because your matched text was at the end of the text node, just pass in `null` as the `refChild`.
- Use [`Node#appendChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) to move the second text node (the one with the matching text) into the `span`. (No need to remove it from its parent first; `appendChild` does that for you.)

Comment: Fun fact: Nearly five years later, they used this code in [the Drumpfinator Chrome extension](http://drumpfinator.com/) connected to *Last Week Tonight* with John Oliver. Hilarious!

Comment: You found that out as well? Oh wait it's your answer? were you consulted or did you look in the extension like me?

Comment: @brace110: A very nice young woman who looked at the source code dropped me an email. :-)

Comment: Using it for something similar myself, with proper attribution of course :)

Comment: Also powers Cloud to Butt! https://github.com/panicsteve/cloud-to-butt/blob/master/Source/content_script.js

Answer (score 13):

[T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904914/javascript-regex-to-replace-text-not-in-html-attributes/5904945#5904945) is correct. I've gone a little further code-wise: here's a fully-formed example that works in all major browsers. I've posted variations of this code on Stack Overflow before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798142/tag-like-autocompletion-and-caret-cursor-movement-in-contenteditable-elements/4026684#4026684) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040495/dom-wrapping-a-substring-in-textnode-with-a-new-span-node/4045531#4045531), for example), and made it nice and generic so I (or anyone else) don't have to change it much to reuse it.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Vf5J/38/

Code:

```
// Reusable generic function
function surroundInElement(el, regex, surrounderCreateFunc) {
    // script and style elements are left alone
    if (!/^(script|style)$/.test(el.tagName)) {
        var child = el.lastChild;
        while (child) {
            if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                surroundInElement(child, regex, surrounderCreateFunc);
            } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                surroundMatchingText(child, regex, surrounderCreateFunc);
            }
            child = child.previousSibling;
        }
    }
}

// Reusable generic function
function surroundMatchingText(textNode, regex, surrounderCreateFunc) {
    var parent = textNode.parentNode;
    var result, surroundingNode, matchedTextNode, matchLength, matchedText;
    while ( textNode && (result = regex.exec(textNode.data)) ) {
        matchedTextNode = textNode.splitText(result.index);
        matchedText = result[0];
        matchLength = matchedText.length;
        textNode = (matchedTextNode.length > matchLength) ?
            matchedTextNode.splitText(matchLength) : null;
        // Ensure searching starts at the beginning of the text node
        regex.lastIndex = 0;
        surroundingNode = surrounderCreateFunc(matchedTextNode.cloneNode(true));
        parent.insertBefore(surroundingNode, matchedTextNode);
        parent.removeChild(matchedTextNode);
    }
}

// This function does the surrounding for every matched piece of text
// and can be customized  to do what you like
function createSpan(matchedTextNode) {
    var el = document.createElement("span");
    el.style.color = "red";
    el.appendChild(matchedTextNode);
    return el;
}

// The main function
function wrapWords(container, words) {
    // Replace the words one at a time to ensure "test2" gets matched
    for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; ++i) {
        surroundInElement(container, new RegExp(words[i]), createSpan);
    }
}

wrapWords(document.getElementById("container"), ["test2", "test"]);
```

Comment: this is just what i was looking for, how could i make this completely ignore case though?

Comment: @MikeMellor: Change `new RegExp(words[i], "g")` to `new RegExp(words[i], "gi")`.

Comment: god that was easy, i really should learn about regular expressions. Thanks Tim

Comment: @MikeMellor: Everyone should learn regular expressions :)

Comment: @TimDown: thanks for the code. However, it must be noted that it has a bug: it skips some matches. To fix it, `regex.lastIndex = 0;` must be added after the `textNode = ...` line in surroundMatchingText.

Comment: @dchervov: I don't think that's true, but I could be wrong. Have you got an example?

Comment: @TimDown: yes, see how it does not highlight one of the "test" words here: https://jsfiddle.net/7Vf5J/36/ . And it does highlight it properly with the suggested fix. lastIndex must be reset to zero because textNode is updated to the remainder of the string - so the search must start from the beginning of the remainder.

Comment: @dchervov: My apologies, you're right. I'll fix it.

Comment: @dchervov: Having had a closer look, I think changing the regular expression to not have its global flag set is a better fix and is how I originally intended the `surroundMatchingText()` function to work.

Comment: @dchervov: ... although your fix makes it work regardless of whether the regex's global flag is set. I'm coming round to your fix instead.

Comment: @TimDown Thank you, this is great ! Any chance you could update it with an optional 3rd argument that would allow to replace text as well ?