# Chrome extension replace text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to replace all the text on the page, for example: all "Hello" to "Hi"

I'm currently using

`body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace("Hello", "Hi");`

I've been running into two problems:

1. there might be Classes or IDs named `Hello` (e.g. `<div id="Hello"></div>`, then it would mess up this code)
2. For some reason Gmail breaks when I try to replace the body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is Chrome-specific and you don't have to worry about legacy browsers (*cough* IE), this sounds like a job for a [treeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTreeWalker). There's a decent example of how to use it [here](http://paul.kinlan.me/dom-treewalker).

Answer (score 1):

Doing that `innerHTML` thing will trash all the event handlers hooked to elements on the page, because what you're doing there is destroying the previous elements and *replacing* them with new ones.

To do what you want to do, you'll have to walk the dom and update the values of the text nodes (only). There's an example, with full code and a [live copy](http://jsbin.com/unuli5), in [this other answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904914/javascript-regex-to-replace-text-not-in-html-attributes/5904945#5904945). You just have to change what the `handleText` function is doing, and you're good to go.