# Highlighting text in document (JavaScript) Efficiently 

Tags: javascript, performance, highlight

How can I (efficiently - not slowing the computer [cpu]) highlight a specific part of a      page?

Lets say that my page is as so:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
"My generic words would be selected here" !.
<script>
//highlight code here
var textToHighlight = 'selected here" !';
//what sould I write here?
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My idea is to "clone" all the body into a variable and find via indexOf the specified text, change(insert a span with a background-color) the "cloned" string and replace the "real" body with the "cloned" one.
I just think that it isn't efficient.
Do you have any other ideas? (be creative :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="myText">"My generic words would be selected here" !.</p>
<script>
//highlight code here
var textToHighlight = 'selected here" !';
var text = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = text.replace(textToHighlight, '<span style="color:red">'+textToHighlight+'</span>');
//what sould I write here?
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are your efficiency concerns? _Efficient_ by itself doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: @SelimOber, I mean by efficient:
- Low CPU consumption

Comment: There are two methods for your operation:
1 - with regulare expression => required many resources (CPU-heavy)
2 - looking for a string and replace without Regex (see my example) => perfomant but not limited to complex strings
Sorry for my Englich

Comment: The bigger problem is the inefficiency of replacing the whole `innerHTML` of a potential complex element, which will dwarf any inefficiency of using a regular expression. The alternative is DOM traversal.

Answer (score 5):

I've adapted the following from my answers to several similar questions on SO ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905413/96100)). It's designed to be reusable and has proved to be so. It traverses the DOM within a container node you specify, searching each text node for the specified text and using DOM methods to split the text node and surround the relevant chunk of text in a styled `<span>` element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HqjZa/

Code:

```
// Reusable generic function
function surroundInElement(el, regex, surrounderCreateFunc) {
    // script and style elements are left alone
    if (!/^(script|style)$/.test(el.tagName)) {
        var child = el.lastChild;
        while (child) {
            if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                surroundInElement(child, regex, surrounderCreateFunc);
            } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                surroundMatchingText(child, regex, surrounderCreateFunc);
            }
            child = child.previousSibling;
        }
    }
}

// Reusable generic function
function surroundMatchingText(textNode, regex, surrounderCreateFunc) {
    var parent = textNode.parentNode;
    var result, surroundingNode, matchedTextNode, matchLength, matchedText;
    while ( textNode && (result = regex.exec(textNode.data)) ) {
        matchedTextNode = textNode.splitText(result.index);
        matchedText = result[0];
        matchLength = matchedText.length;
        textNode = (matchedTextNode.length > matchLength) ?
            matchedTextNode.splitText(matchLength) : null;
        surroundingNode = surrounderCreateFunc(matchedTextNode.cloneNode(true));
        parent.insertBefore(surroundingNode, matchedTextNode);
        parent.removeChild(matchedTextNode);
    }
}

// This function does the surrounding for every matched piece of text
// and can be customized  to do what you like
function createSpan(matchedTextNode) {
    var el = document.createElement("span");
    el.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    el.appendChild(matchedTextNode);
    return el;
}

// The main function
function wrapText(container, text) {
    surroundInElement(container, new RegExp(text, "g"), createSpan);
}

wrapText(document.body, "selected here");
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the parent node. so in that aspect it wont be that efficient.

Comment: @agam360: You don't need to know the parent node, only an ancestor node. You need that for an `innerHTML` solution too, and my solution will generally outperform one based on `innerHTML`, as well as being more robust (think of an attribute containing the search term, for example).

Comment: How do you cleanup anything which was wrapped, before wrapping again? see [demo](http://jsbin.com/hizihoq/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**this**](http://webcloud.se/log/Selecting-text-with-JavaScript/) in combination with [**this**](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/) and you should be pretty ok. (It is almost better than trying to implement selection / selection-highlighting logic yourself.)