# Place tags around certain text within contenteditable without moving cursor

Tags: javascript, html, text, contenteditable, cursor-position

I am working on a simple (I thought) word processor. It uses contenteditable. I have a list of words that I want to always appear highlighted.

```
<article contenteditable="true" class="content">
    <p>Once upon a time, there were a couple of paragraphs. Some things were <b>bold</b>, and other things were <i>italic.</i></p>
    <p>Then down here there was the word highlight. It should have a different color background.</p>
</article>
```

So basically what I need is a way to wrap a word in `<span>` tags. This has proven more difficult than I expected.

Here was what I tried first:

```
var text = document.querySelector('article.content').innerHTML
    start = text.indexOf("highlight"),
    end = start + "highlight".length;
text = text.splice(end, 0, "</span>");
text = text.splice(start, 0, "<span>");
document.querySelector('article.content').innerHTML = text;
```

It uses the `splice` method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/).

And it does exactly what I need it to do, with one big issue: the cursor gets moved. Because all the text is replaced, the cursor loses its place, which isn't a good thing for a text editor.

I've also tried a couple times using `document.createRange`, but the issue is that while given the start and end points of a range only includes visible characters, `text.indexOf("highlight")` gives the index including the tags and such.

A few ideas which I'm not sure how to execute:

- Figure out where the cursor begins and place it there again after using the code above
- Find the difference in indexes between `createRange` and `indexOf`
- Maybe there's already a library with this kind of functionality that I just can't find

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend against doing this by manipulating `innerHTML`. It's inefficient and error-prone (think of the case where the content contains an element with a class of "highlight", for example). Here's an example of doing this using DOM methods to manipulate the text nodes directly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10618517/96100

Maintaining the caret position can be achieved a number of ways. You could use a [character offset-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17694760/96100), which has some disadvantages due to not considering line breaks implied by `<br>` and block elements but is relatively simple. Alternatively, you could use the [selection save and restore module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule) of my Rangy library, which may be overkill for your needs, but the same approach could be used.

Here is an example using the first approach:

http://jsbin.com/suwogaha/1