# Modify text in a contenteditable div without resetting the caret (cursor) position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, contenteditable

I am trying to replace any instances of `/any thing in here/` with `<b>/any thing in here/</b>` on the fly, as changes are made in a contenteditable div.

My current implementation works, but at every keypress the caret is moved to the beginning of div making the implementation unusable. Is there some way to keep the caret position while replacing the div's contents?

```
$('.writer').on('keyup', function(e) {
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\/(.*)\//g, '<b>\/$1\/<\/b>'));
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use a `div` with `contenteditable` instead of a `textarea` or something similar?

Comment: @Luxelin: I'd like to render html within the div, and as far as I am aware, html can't be rendered inside a textarea.

Comment: Even if you were to use a textarea I'm sure the caret would still move around.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div?rq=1) may be of use for you, regarding setting the caret position.

Comment: I've answered a very similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24687874/96100

Answer (score 6):

```js
$('#writer').on('keyup', function(e) {
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var end_node = range.endContainer;
            var end = range.endOffset;
            if(end_node != this){
                var text_nodes = get_text_nodes_in(this);
                for (var i = 0; i < text_nodes.length; ++i) {
                    if(text_nodes[i] == end_node){
                        break;
                    }
                    end += text_nodes[i].length;
                }
            }
            var html = $(this).html();
            if(/\&nbsp;$/.test(html) && $(this).text().length == end){
                end = end - 1;
                set_range(end,end,this);
                return;
            }
            var filter = html.replace(/(<b>)?\/([^<\/]*)(<\/b>)?/g, '\/$2');
            console.log(filter);
            filter = filter.replace(/(<b>)?([^<\/]*)\/(<\/b>)?/g, '$2\/');
            console.log(filter);
            filter = filter.replace(/(<b>)?\/([^<\/]*)\/(<\/b>)?/g, '<b>\/$2\/<\/b>');
            console.log(filter);
            if(!/\&nbsp;$/.test($(this).html())){
                filter += '&nbsp;';
            }
            $(this).html(filter);
            set_range(end,end,this);
    
        });
        
        $('#writer').on('mouseup', function(e) {
            if(!/\&nbsp;$/.test($(this).html())){
                return;
            }
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var end = range.endOffset;
            var end_node = range.endContainer;
            if(end_node != this){
                var text_nodes = get_text_nodes_in(this);
                for (var i = 0; i < text_nodes.length; ++i) {
                    if(text_nodes[i] == end_node){
                        break;
                    }
                    end += text_nodes[i].length;
                }
            }
            if($(this).text().length == end){
                end = end - 1;
                set_range(end,end,this);
            }
        });
        
        function get_text_nodes_in(node) {
            var text_nodes = [];
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                text_nodes.push(node);
            } else {
                var children = node.childNodes;
                for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    var text_node
                    text_nodes.push.apply(text_nodes, get_text_nodes_in(children[i]));
                }
            }
            return text_nodes;
        }
        
        function set_range(start, end, element) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            var text_nodes = get_text_nodes_in(element);
            var foundStart = false;
            var char_count = 0, end_char_count;
    
            for (var i = 0, text_node; text_node = text_nodes[i++]; ) {
                end_char_count = char_count + text_node.length;
                if (!foundStart && start >= char_count && (start < end_char_count || (start === end_char_count && i < text_nodes.length))) {
                    range.setStart(text_node, start - char_count);
                    foundStart = true;
                }
                if (foundStart && end <= end_char_count) {
                    range.setEnd(text_node, end - char_count);
                    break;
                }
                char_count = end_char_count;
            }
    
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="writer" contenteditable style="width:300px;height:100px;border:1px solid #ccc;">/input some words here!/</div>
```

Comment: Great job! But it's not working correctly with return button input (at least in Chrome).