# JavaScript / HTML: Replace word in input / contentEditable -> caret moves to the left

Tags: javascript, html, replace, caret

My situation is, that I have some kind of an inputbox in HTML (right now it's a contentEditable div) `element` in which I want to replace one specific word a user can type in, with one other word:

```
word1 = "hello";
word2 = "<b>hello</b>";
//element = some random element that supports innerHTML
element.oninput = function(){
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(word1, word2);
}
```

So if the user types "hello", it is automatically replace with a bold "hello", which works only if I use an element with the property `innerHTML`, so I can insert the `<b>`. Now my problem is, that once the innerHTML is replaced (l. 5), the caret jumps back in front of the first letter in the div:

`[this is a hell|] -> [|this is a <b>hello</b>]`

What can I do to prevent that from happening without using jQuery?

*I can also change the element type/class, it just needs to support `innerHTML`...*

Comment: Possible duplicate [Modify text in a contenteditable div without reseting the caret (cursor) position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845254/modify-text-in-a-contenteditable-div-without-reseting-the-caret-cursor-positio).

Comment: Close enough. I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576694/saving-and-restoring-caret-position-for-contenteditable-div

Comment: @ScottMarcus It doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @Unknown There were sever suggestions that seemed to work on that page. Did you look through all of them?

Comment: @seahorsepip Doesn't work either. The caret stays in the first position once the word to replace is entered.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I tried the second one, as it appeared to make sense.