# How to modify content of a text node using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing a browser extension using javascript to highlight key words. So far I have filtered the DOM tree to get all  the leaf nodes. But I have problems modifying these nodes because they are leaf nodes (`nodeType == 3`). `node.nodeValue = '<em>keyword</em> is highlighted'` doesn't work because angle brackets are escaped. `replaceChild` can't work either since something like `'<em>keyword</em> is highlighted'` is not a single node but actually a collection of nodes and I don't want to wrap them into one node.

Comment: You are actually wanting to append a new node here with a tag of `<em>` so append that to the node in question, add the contained `keyword` to the new node and then append the other text to the `leaf`

Answer (score 3):

Some basic DOM manipulation will do it. Use the text node `splitText()` method twice to create three text nodes, move the middle text node containing the keyword into your highlight element and the insert your `<em>` element in between the remaining two text nodes.

**Example**

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6228e/

HTML:

```
<div id="example">This text contains a keyword to highlight</div>
```

JavaScript to highlight the keyword:

```
var div = document.getElementById("example");
var textNode = div.firstChild;
var keyword = "keyword";
var keywordIndex = textNode.data.indexOf(keyword);
if (keywordIndex > -1) {
    // First, split at the start of the keyword
    var keywordTextNode = textNode.splitText(keywordIndex);

    // Now split off the section after the keyword
    var textNodeAfterKeyword = keywordTextNode.splitText(keyword.length);

    // We now have three text nodes containing the text before the keyword,
    // the keyword itself and the text after the keyword.

    // Create the highlight element and put the keyword text node inside it
    var highlightEl = document.createElement("em");
    highlightEl.appendChild(keywordTextNode);

    // Insert the highlight element and we're done
    div.insertBefore(highlightEl, textNodeAfterKeyword);
}
```

This only works for the specific case of an element containing a single text node containing a single keyword. For a more general solution, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10618517/96100

Comment: Quite an intuitive way