# Add class to element in the DOM based on content

Tags: javascript, html, dom, replace, addclass

***EDIT -- the issue appears to be in the way I'm trying to add a class (I tried changing some CSS for the class to test and it doesn't do anything)

I want to find an element in the DOM based on text, and add a class to it, so that I can manipulate it/its parent elements

This is the function I wrote to do this (before this I'm using a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904914/javascript-regex-to-replace-text-not-in-html-attributes/5904945#5904945) from stackoverflow to walk through the DOM , and call my function to replace the matches- (the actual string values are not important right now) -- the HTML I'm modifying is the DOM.

```
var MATCH = ['word'];
var REPLACE = ['other'];


   function replaceText(textNode) {
    var badWord = textNode.nodeValue;
    var replaceWord = "";
    badWord.className = "filter";

    //Go through and match/replace strings equal to MATCH
    for (var i=0; i< MATCH.length; i++) {
        replaceWord = document.getElementsByClassName("filter").innerHTML;
        replaceWord = replaceWord.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + MATCH[i] + '\\b', 'g'), REPLACE[i]);
    }
    textNode.nodeValue = replaceWord;
}
```

It works when I just directly replace the text in the word like this below - but I want to access and modify from the class, so that I can change the parent elements/css

```
//working version without adding class
function hide(textNode) {
    var badWord = textNode.nodeValue;

    //Go through and match/replace strings equal to MATCH
    for (var i=0; i< MATCH.length; i++) {
        badWord = badWord.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + MATCH[i] + '\\b', 'g'), REPLACE[i]);
    }
    textNode.nodeValue = badWord;
}
```

function from stackoverflow post -

```
walk(document.body);

function walk(node) {

    var child, next;

    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case ELEMENT:  // Element
        case DOCUMENT:  // Document
        case DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT: // Document fragment
            child = node.firstChild;
            while (child) {
                next = child.nextSibling;
                walk(child);
                child = next;
            }
            break;

        case TEXT: // Text node
            replaceText(node);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You use addClass on a nodeValue, which will not work, try `textNode.className = 'filter';`. If there are multiple classes 'filter', you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('filter')` to get them all. For a complete answer, please update your post with the HTML you are trying to modify, the word(s) to be replaced and link to the stackoverflow post with the DOM parse function.

Comment: @M4tini added the link - I'm modifying the current page - this is for a chrome extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your `replaceText()` function and tested it on this page. It replaces text and adds a filter class on the nodes with replaced text. This solution uses `classList.add('filter')` which is not supported in IE9 and earlier, but that's no issue since this code is for a Chrome extension.

```
function replaceText(textNode) {
    var nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue;
    for (var i=0; i < MATCH.length; i++) {
        if(-1 != nodeValue.indexOf(MATCH[i])) {
            nodeValue = nodeValue.replace(new RegExp(MATCH[i], 'g'), REPLACE[i]);
            textNode.parentNode.classList.add('filter');
        }
    }
    textNode.nodeValue = nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: FYI - I had to change the case values in that `walk()` function to get it working, for example: `DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT` to `Node.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE`.