# Can't use č and ć in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that should replace certain words with others. The problem is it won't replace words that contain serbian latin characters like Č, Ć, Ž, Đ or Š. Here is my code:

```js
var exprs = [
  //Example
  [/\bČ\b/g, "Ć"],
]

function replaceTextInNode(node) {
  var value = node.nodeValue
  var expr
  for (expr of exprs) {
    value = value.replace(expr[0], expr[1])
  }
  node.nodeValue = value
}

function walk(node) {
  var child, next

  switch (node.nodeType) {
    case 1:   // element
    case 9:   // document
    case 11:  // fragment
      child = node.firstChild
      while (child) {
        next = child.nextSibling
        walk(child)
        child = next
      }
      break

    case 3:   // text
      replaceTextInNode(node)
      break
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  walk(document.body)
})

document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(e) {
  walk(e.target)
})
```

Everything is saved as UTF8

Code is based on: [Javascript Regex to replace text NOT in html attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904914/javascript-regex-to-replace-text-not-in-html-attributes/5904945#5904945)

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Javascript handling of `\b` in regex because it works for `/Č/g`. Rework your regex. See also [Javascript + Unicode regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/280762)

Comment: And to add to wOxxOm's remark, `/u` option for regexes is already supported in Chrome. You should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using unicode escape characters, for example [Č as `\u010c`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10d/index.htm). Usually when I have weird character issues converting them to unicode solves it.