# auto keywords selected in site

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, web

As we often see in some sites, our search keywords are already selected in the site paragraphs.

same as those selection comes if we search something in browser( e.g. in crome ctrl+F)

how this can be achieved.

thanks,

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241169/highlight-search-terms-select-only-leaf-nodes

Comment: You can get the referrer using PHP for example, then you can parse out the search terms if the referrer was Google. (You asked for JavaScript but I'm not completely sure what you're asking here)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - the question that has been linked to gives the answer for *how to highlight terms using JavaScript/jQuery* but (as I understand it) this question is asking how to highlight the keywords when a user reaches the site by following a link from the results page of a search engine query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps to this:

1. Make use of the [`referer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) property - in JavaScript, you can get it from [`document.referrer`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp) (also see [MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer)) *(note the difference in spelling from the HTTP Header)*- to see if the user arrived at your page from a search engine and then extract the search keywords.
2. Use regex to highlight keywords on the page

---

If you'd rather not work on this yourself, here are some pre-baked scripts you might be able to make use of:

***Plain old*** JavaScript

- [searchhi](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/searchhi/) - a JavaScript library that does what you seem to want
- [JavaScript keyword highlighting](http://eriwen.com/javascript/highlight-search-results-with-js/)
- [More JavaScript keyword highlighting](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm)

**jQuery**

- [jQuery serach keyword highlighting plugin](https://github.com/hail2u/jquery.highlight-search-terms)
- [jQuery highlighting plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)