# How to highlight words in html using jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)

I want to highlight certain words in html `<body>` tag, but I want to avoid highlighting those which are within `<a>` tag. How can this be done? By highlight I mean, underlining and making word bold.

For e.g I have this html content

```
<body>
<p>
This is sample text for the purpose of highlighting searched text. Please visit <a href="javascript:void(0)">www.sampleSite.com</a>
</p>
</body>
```

Now when I search for the word "sample", I would not want to highlight the word **sample** contained within that anchor tag.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. jQuery plugin to do highlighting:

```
/**
* jQuery plugin to replace text strings
*
* Taken from @link http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/spotlight-jquery-replacetext/
*/

$.fn.replaceText = function( search, replace, text_only ) {
return this.each(function(){
        var node = this.firstChild,
        val, new_val, remove = [];
        if ( node ) {
            do {
              if ( node.nodeType === 3 ) {
                val = node.nodeValue;
                new_val = val.replace( search, replace );
                if ( new_val !== val ) {
                  if ( !text_only && /</.test( new_val ) ) {
                    $(node).before( new_val );
                    remove.push( node );
                  } else {
                    node.nodeValue = new_val;
                  }
                }
              }
            } while ( node = node.nextSibling );
        }
        remove.length && $(remove).remove();
    });
};
```

#### 2. CSS to style a `span` element with a single `highlight` class

```css
span.highlight{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

#### 3. jQuery code to run after you have included the plugin & style:

```
// replace partial string occurrences with a span css styled element
// i.e. textsample => text<span class="highlight">sample</span>
$('p').replaceText(/(sample)/gi, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
```

OR as suggested by @Nick C. in the comments

```
// replace full string occurrences with a span css styled element
// i.e. ONLY sample => <span class="highlight">sample</span>
$('p').replaceText(/\b(sample)\b/gi, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/vV865/)

The plugin is smart enough not to replace the element's attributes, or text inside elements such as `a` element...

Comment: I recommend using word boundaries (\b) to match words. For example, $("p").replaceText(/\b(rain)\b/gi, ...) will match "rain", but not "train".

Comment: @Nick C.: Well, that's up to the OP if partial occurrences should be highlighted or not. Nonetheless, I will add it in there. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I had to make changes to make it powerful enough to do what I wanted.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15212744/470749