# using jquery, how to highlight search term in ajax response HTML content

Tags: jquery, highlighting

I am seeing plenty of libraries and plugins for finding a search term in a regular page, but they are not written to handle highlighting a string within ajax response content.  E.g. many scripts I find do the call to the main function like for example:

```
`returnDataSearchTermHighlightified = highlight(searchString);`
```

(^^^ from the accepted answer at: [Highlight search terms (select only leaf nodes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241169/highlight-search-terms-select-only-leaf-nodes))

...where that `highlight()` function's missing second param is auto-populated with the entire HTML body of the page.  But in my case I am not wanting to highlight keywords in the parent body, but in the ajax response content only (a div I populate in the parent body), and so I cannot do e.g. this:

```
returnDataSearchTermHighlightified = highlight(searchString);
```

...and if I try this:

```
...
var jqxhr = $.ajax(

        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxWorkerSourceUrl,
            data: form_data,
            timeout: 15000
        }
    )
    .success(function(returnData) {
        $("#ajaxSpinner").fadeOut('slow');
        searchString = 'example';
        returnDataSearchTermHighlightified = highlight(searchString, returnData);
```

...then the page seems to load my ajax response with no error, but that response content is empty!
Can anyone point me to fixing this?  .. or even to a library or plugin designed to handle keyword highlighting in jquery ajax response content?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe using `async:true` will do the trick

Comment: Where are you using `returnData`?

Comment: should work fine as long as your function works properly and you insert `returnDataSearchTermHighlightified` into DOM

Comment: you can also use jQuery on html response by wrapping it in `$()`

Comment: I believe `highlight(searchString, $(returnData))` will do the trick.

Comment: `returnDataSearchTermHighlightified`  is redundant. `highlight` returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `function highlight(term, base)` requires `base` to be of type Element or jQuery .

Try

```
.success(function(returnData) {
        $("#ajaxSpinner").fadeOut('slow');
        var searchString = 'example',
            base = $(returnData);
        highlight(searchString, base);
        base.appendTo(document.body); //whatever you were going to do..
```

Comment: hmm.. I do try that and I am getting the same result - that my target div in the parent just populates with nothing at all (no error).

Comment: Check `base.length` before and after highlight function call. Like this `console.log(base.length)` or better `console.log(base.html())`

Comment: your tip made me think and look at the code in a way that led me to the answer (anyway it works now for me).  As you said I needed to be using:

`base = $(returnData);`

instead of 

`base = returnData;`

...with:

`returnDataSearchTermHighlightified = highlight(searchString, base);`

...and then the other thing that was killing it (and baffles me that was missing from the accepted answer, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3241437/530006  ), was some return output from the `highlight(term, base) {}` function.  See my comment to that answer.